# MySQL JOIN based on dynamic LIKE statement between multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-like

I have a table called **`faq`**. This table consists from fields `faq_id`,`faq_subject`.
I have another table called **`article`** which consists of `article_id`,`ticket_id`,`a_body` and which stores articles in a specific ticket. Naturally there is also a table "ticket" with fields `ticket_id`,`ticket_number`.

I want to retrieve a result table in format:
`ticket_number`,`faq_id`,`faq_subject`.

In order to do this I need to search for `faq_id` in the `article`.`a_body` field using %LIKE% statement.

My question is, how can I do this dynamically such that I return with SQL one result table, which is in format `ticket_number`,`faq_id`,`faq_subject`.

I tried multiple configurations of `UNION ALL`, `LEFT JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` statements, but they all return either too many rows, or have different problems.

Is this even possible with MySQL, and is it possible to write an SQL statement which includes @variables and can take care of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, that kind of a design is problematic. You have certain data embedded within another column, which is going to cause logic as well as performance problems (since you can't index the `a_body` in such a way that it will help the `JOIN`). If this is a one-time thing then that's one issue, but otherwise you're going to have problems with this design.

Second, consider this example: You're searching for `faq_id` #123. You have an article that includes `faq_id` 4123. You're going to end up with a false match there. You can embed the `faq_id` values in the text with some sort of mark-up (for example, `[faq_id:123]`), but at that point you might as well be saving them off in another table as well.

The following query should work (I think that MySQL supports `CAST`, if not then you might need to adjust that).

```
SELECT
    T.ticket_number,
    F.faq_id,
    F.faq_subject
FROM
    Articles A
INNER JOIN FAQs F ON
    A.a_body LIKE CONCAT('%', F.faq_id, '%')
INNER JOIN Tickets T ON
    T.ticket_id = A.ticket_id
```

**EDIT:** Corrected to use `CONCAT`

Comment: `CAST` in this case is not necessary, and will throw an error in MySQL.

Comment: I think it will work if I rewrite  "A.a_body LIKE '%' + CAST(F.faq_id AS VARCHAR) + '%'" in MySQL friendly manner.

Comment: You should at least use some markup around the ID, and/or save it to a different table, as this answer suggests, to avoid the 123 vs. 4123 problem. To make the query work, you should use `CONCAT` as Karolis suggests. In MySQL you can't concatenate with `+`, and you can't `CAST AS VARCHAR` - see [`CAST` docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

Comment: This is the correct answer : SELECT
    T.tn,
    F.f_number,
    F.f_subject
FROM
    article A
INNER JOIN faq_item F ON
    A.a_body LIKE CONCAT('%', F.f_number, '%')
INNER JOIN ticket T ON
    T.id = A.ticket_id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.ticket_number, f.faq_id, f.faq_subject
FROM faq.f
INNER JOIN article a ON (a.a_body RLIKE CONCAT('faq_id: ',faq_id))
INNER JOIN ticket t ON (t.ticket_id = a.ticket_id)
WHERE somecriteria
```